# How to get execution times of Azure Function steps?

Tags: performance, logging, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function set up as illustrated bellow. I need to understand the execution times for Trigger, Function, and Output steps because even after the function is "warm", first request takes up to 7 seconds. After that the execution time drops to something like 100 ms.

[image: Azure Function set up]

So far I switched the logging level in `host.json` to

```
"logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Host.Results": "Error",
      "Function": "Trace",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Trace"
    }
  }
```

and watched the simple telemetry in live logs:

1. 8:48:07 AM | Trace Request successfully matched the route with name 'main' and template 'api/{*segments}'
2. 8:48:06 AM | Trace Executing 'Functions.main' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=...)

That's pretty much all I see. Also, when opening the Application - Functions - Function - main log from Visual Studio, the log levels still have [Information] preable.

What I would like to see is basically a duration-time output as in the monitor (from Functions - Main in web portal) section, but split by steps. For example:

```
date | step     | success | result code | duration (ms) 
---------------------------------------------------------
.... | trigger  | success | 200         | 39
.... | function | success | 200         | 32
.... | output   | success | 200         | 37
```

How to get the duration time for Trigger, Function, and Output steps on every execution?

Comment: Check the `requests` table in application insights. It would have the total time of a request execution.

Comment: I did that with `requests
| summarize RequestsCount=sum(itemCount), AverageDuration=avg(duration), percentiles(duration, 50, 95, 99) by operation_Name
| order by RequestsCount desc` but there is only Main shown. Do you have another query suggestion?